# Can #undef affect member functions in C++?

Tags: c++, linker, unreal-engine4, undef

I have an Unreal Engine 4 project with several plugins. On of these plugins contains a `FileHelper` class with a method `CreateFile`. This has worked fine for months, but in a recent commit, a different plugin added a call to `FileHelper::CreateFile` and now sometimes I get a linker error saying that `CreateFileW` is not a member of `FileHelper` (this doesn't appear in every build, which I cannot yet explain).
I went on to undefine `CreateFile` temporarily like this

```
#include "UtilPlugin/File/FileSystemHelper.h"

#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma push_macro("CreateFile")
#undef CreateFile
#endif //_WIN32

...//new code including CreateFile call

#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma pop_macro("CreateFile")
#endif //_WIN32
```

but now I get errors

> C2039 'CreateFile': is not a member of 'FileSystemHelper'
>
> C3861 'CreateFile': identifier not found

Since I know `CreateFile` is successfully called in other places (at least within the same plugin as the `FileSystemHelper`), I know that it exists.

Thus my question is, if the undefine can affect member functions like this.
I have moved the `#undef` part above the includes in code and I don't get an error anymore, but since it occurred seemingly randomly, I'm not entirely sure that I really fixed the problem.

Comment: `#undef` is a preprocessor directive. The preprocessor modifies the code (e.g. source file inclusion or macro expansion) and the compiler compiles the modified code, not the original code.

Comment: Presumably the macro was defined when the `CreateFile` function was defined causing the definition to actually be for `CreateFileW` or `CreateFileA`

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. Wouldn't that mean `#undef` affects the member regardless of whether it is put before or after the include in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following shows a problematic case:

```
#define CreateFile CreateFileW

struct S
{
    void CreateFile(); // Actually void CreateFileW();
};
```

And then

```
#undef CreateFile

void foo()
{
   S s;
   s.CreateFile(); // Error, "expect" s.CreateFileW()
}
```

As `#define` might modify meaning of code (locally), `#undef` "cancels" that modification locally too.

Comment: so since the define is from some windows or unreal header and I can't simply remove it, the correct way would be do undefine it in the file with (in your example) `struct S{...}` ?

Comment: "correct" way is mostly a workaround to avoid that the MACRO leaks to some other parts of the code :-/.
Renaming your `CreateFile` would also fix the issue, or ensure that the MACRO is defined everywhere might also be an option.